# bundle update puma won't work

Tags: ruby, bundle, puma, gemfile

I tried using `bundle update puma`but I get a `Could not locate Gemfile` error. I'm in the same directory as the gemfile. My `dir` has

```
26/02/2017  12:39 AM               490 puma
26/02/2017  12:39 AM               234 puma.bat
26/02/2017  12:39 AM               493 pumactl
26/02/2017  12:39 AM               237 pumactl.bat
```

Comment: You say you are in the same directory as Gemfile but then list current dir with 4 files, none of which is Gemfile??

Comment: isn't puma a gemfile? If not, how do I find my gemfile?

Comment: I assume we are talking about a ruby-on-rails setup, in which case the Gemfile is in the top level of the directory created at the beginning

Comment: I entered this code to install the puma gemfile : gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl

Comment: Ok, so now I am confused then why you would be using bundle which is a rails command and hence why you are getting the Gemfile error.  If you installed puma with gem and are simply looking to update it, then use gem update puma (you may still need the openssl reference, not sure as have not done that before myself)

Comment: okay I'll try thanks